# Is there a way to run a PC Steam game on my Mac

Tags: steam, macos, splinter-cell-chaos-theory

I just replaced my Macbook for an IMac. I saw that they released Splinter Cell Chaos Theory on Steam, complete with MP :-O . It is only for windows however. Is there a way I can run some sort of program or emulator to play this game? My over all computer knowledge is somewhat limited. You might have to break it down Barney Style. The game should not require  much power to run, it was an XBOX/PS2 game when it came out. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Those are old, might be new info out there.

Comment: That may be so, but according to our community standards, I have to mention it. At the very least, look into the solutions presented there and see if one of them will work for you.

Comment: Install and use steam through wine: http://www.winehq.org/

Comment: There's also a pretty good answer (ahem) [over here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/13335/13845)

Comment: I had downloaded Wine last night. I have Steam on my Mac already. Do I need to re-download Steam(Windows Version)? And run Steam(Windows) through Wine? Or do I use Wine just for the game I want(Use Steam through OS X)?

Comment: Steam has their own built-in WINE emulator nowadays. You can enable Steam Play for titles and it will act as if it's a Windows install. I do it with my Linux OS all the time :)

Answer (score -1):

You can run both OSX and Windows on your Mac, so if you install and boot to Windows then you can play Windows games on Steam. You could also use vmware or virtualbox to run a Windows VM, but playing complex 3d games in a VM is not advised.

Comment: What would you consider complex?

Comment: @Alex Anything with 3D graphics