# Are Steam games on macOS and Microsoft compatible?

Tags: steam, macos, windows

I've been downloading and playing strategy games on my Mac device, and I'm about to buy a new gaming laptop.

Will all my Steam games on my Mac device be playable on my Windows device?

Comment: There are quite a lot of posts on our site that are very similar to this question, if not the same.  Check these out: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/13335/can-i-play-games-made-for-windows-on-a-mac?rq=1 https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/148395/do-i-need-to-buy-the-same-steam-game-twice-for-two-different-operating-systems

Comment: There are special cases, like [CoD Black Ops](https://store.steampowered.com/app/42700/Call_of_Duty_Black_Ops/) which has a totally separate version for Mac. In general though, there's an icon for each OS a game supports on the Steam store page, and owning a license entities a user to have access to the product on all available platforms.

Comment: Procedurally casting close vote per Timmy Jim's comment.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a game is developed for Windows and then it receives a port to macOS, so it's reasonable to think that you should be able to play them all.

There are rare cases of low end indie titles that were Mac-exclusive over the years, according to Reddit.